# Prove that there exists a constant $C$ such that $[z^n]\exp(z/(1-z)) = O(\exp(C\sqrt{n})) $

Tags: asymptotics, generating-functions

Prove that there exists a constant $C$ such that:

$$[z^n]\exp(z/(1-z)) = O(\exp(C\sqrt{n})).$$

The bound of $z$ is $\vert z \vert<\frac14$

Answer (score 5):

Clearly, $f(z)=\exp\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)$ is analytic in the open unit disk $D(0,1)$. Thus,
$$
\forall\,z\in D(0,1),\qquad f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n
$$ 
and we are seeking a bound on $a_n$.

Consider $r$  a positive real from $(0,1)$ then, by Cauchy's formula applied to the circle $C^+(0,r)$, we have
$$
a_n=\frac{1}{2\pi r^n}\int_0^{2\pi}f(re^{i\theta})e^{-in\theta}d\theta
$$
Thus,
$$
\vert a_n\vert\leq\frac{1}{  r^n}\sup_{\theta\in\Bbb{R}}  \vert f(re^{i\theta})\vert \tag{1}
$$
But, 
 $$\eqalign{\vert f(re^{i\theta})\vert&=\exp\left(\hbox{Re}\frac{re^{i\theta}}{1-re^{i\theta}}\right)
=\exp\left(\frac{r(\cos\theta-r)}{\vert r-e^{i\theta}\vert^2}\right)\cr
&\leq 
\exp\left(\frac{r(1-r)}{(1-r)^2}\right)=\exp\left(\frac{r}{1-r}\right)}$$
Hence, from $(1)$ we get, for $0<r<1$
$$
\vert a_n\vert\leq\frac{1}{  r^n}\exp\left(\frac{r}{1-r}\right) \tag{2}
$$
Now, taking $r=\dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{1+\sqrt{n}}$ so that $\frac{r}{1-r}=\sqrt{n}$, we obtain
$$
\vert a_n\vert\leq\left(1+\frac{1}{  \sqrt{n}}\right)^n\exp\left(\sqrt{n}\right) \tag{3}
$$
finally, using the well-known inequality $1+t\leq e^t$ with $t=1/\sqrt{n}$ we get
$\vert a_n\vert\leq e^{2\sqrt{n}}$, which is the desired conclusion.